# Connect another computer in local network

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, local

I'm trying to connect another computer in local network via python (subprocesses module) with this commands from CMD.exe

- `net use \\\\ip\C$ password /user:username`
- `copy D:\file.txt \\ip\C$`

Then in python it look like below.
But when i try second command, I get:

> "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]"

Have you met same problem?
Is there any way to fix it?

```
import subprocess as sp

code = sp.call(r'net use \\<ip>\C$ <pass> /user:<username>')
print(code)
sp.call(r'copy D:\file.txt \\<ip>\C$')
```

Comment: You should use `shutil.copy` for the second operation, not a system call to copy a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `copy` is a built-in, not a real command in Windows.

Those Windows messages are awful, but `"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]"` doesn't mean one of source & destination files can't be accessed (if `copy` failed, you'd get a normal Windows message with explicit file names).

Here, it means that the *command* could not be accessed.

So you'd need to add `shell=True` to your subprocess call to gain access to built-ins.

But don't do that (security issues, non-portability), use `shutil.copy` instead.

Aside, use `check_call` instead of `call` for your first command, as if `net use` fails, the rest will fail too. Better have an early failure.

To sum it up, here's what I would do:

```
import shutil
import subprocess as sp
sp.check_call(['net','use',r'\\<ip>\C$','password','/user:<username>'])
shutil.copy(r'D:\file.txt,r'\\<ip>\C$')
```

Answer (score -1):

you need make sure you have right to add a file.
i have testted successfully after i corrected the shared dirctory's right.

Comment: {net use D: \\<ip>\C$ <pass> /user:<username>} - this one gives a mistake also in cmd

Comment: this is a shared directory, are you sure you have right to add file ?

Comment: `copy` isn't an executable, not possible to use `subprocess` on it without `shell=True`